# Multiply each row of one dataframe by all rows of column in second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.

Df1

| ID # | Date | Units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1821 | 01/01/22 | 300 |
| 1821 | 01/02/22 | 450 |

Df2

| ID # | Hour | % of daily total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1821 | 0 | 0.57 |
| 1821 | 1 | 0.89 |
| 1821 | 2 | 1.23 |
| 1821 | 3 | 5.46 |

I'd like to multiply each row in df1 by all rows in df2. Specifically where both ID #'s match.

Final dataframe units represents the units (300 and 450) from df1 multiplied by the % of daily total ( 0.57%, 0.89%, 1.23%, 5.46%) from df2.

| ID # | Date | Hour | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1821 | 01/01/22 | 0 | 2 |
| 1821 | 01/01/22 | 1 | 3 |
| 1821 | 01/01/22 | 2 | 4 |
| 1821 | 01/01/22 | 3 | 16 |
| 1821 | 01/02/22 | 0 | 3 |
| 1821 | 01/02/22 | 1 | 4 |
| 1821 | 01/02/22 | 2 | 6 |
| 1821 | 01/02/22 | 3 | 25 |

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't think the question is clear enough. Also, how did the Units become 2,3,4,16?

Comment: In order to get 2,3,4,16 you would multiply the units (300) from df1 by the % of daily total( 0.57%, 0.89%, 1.23%, 5.46%) from df2 to get 2,3,4,16. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you multiply each row from df1 by each row from df2 your final result must contain `(4x2) = 8` results. Are you sure the all ids in df1 is correct?

Comment: @ErselEr I've corrected my final output per your point given df1 & df2

Comment: @Will: looks like I'm having basic maths issues here :). `300*0.57*0.89*1.23*5.46` is around `1022` and `300*(0.57/100)*(0.89/100)*(1.23/100)*(5.46/100)` is a very small number i.e., less that 0.00...

Answer (score 0):

`Merge` the dataframes on `ID #`, then `pop` & `multiply` the column `Units` and `% of daily total`, then divide by 100 and round the get the desired result

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='ID #', how='left')
df3['Units'] = df3.pop('Units').mul(df3.pop('% of daily total'), fill_value=1).div(100).round()
```

---

```
print(df3)

   ID #      Date  Hour  Units
0  1821  01/01/22     0    2.0
1  1821  01/01/22     1    3.0
2  1821  01/01/22     2    4.0
3  1821  01/01/22     3   16.0
4  1821  01/02/22     0    3.0
5  1821  01/02/22     1    4.0
6  1821  01/02/22     2    6.0
7  1821  01/02/22     3   25.0
```